# How to encrypt form data?

Tags: php, html, forms, encryption, passwords

I have a login form that will submit id and password to a php file which will then check that id and pw against data in an SQL database. How can i encrypt the outgoing form data to make sure nobody can see it until it gets to its destination?
the login form code is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Login page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="login" action="fetchalldata.php" method="post">
Username : <input type="text" name="userid"/>
Password : <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Login"/>
</body>
</html>
```

would prehashing the password on the database and
sending a hashed password be more effective?

Comment: [Use SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer)

Comment: Well I believe GoDaddy offers cheap SSL certificates.

Comment: I'm not planning on buying SSL certificates..

Comment: @lonewaft You should. All other so called "solutions" are half baked fake security "solutions". (not saying SSL has no flaws)

Comment: then don't plan on having the data submitted securely.

Comment: @Dagon how exactly does HTTPS work? is it easy to setup, and most importantly will it encrypt the data securely?

Comment: so you do plan to buy a SSL certificate then? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https

Comment: If it is absolutely the only way to go, yes, but that's a last resort.

Comment: @lonewaft It is absolutely the only way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SSL is *the* answer.  The only answer.

However, if you must try go go with a home brew solution here is an idea to consider:

- Have the PHP code provide Javascript with the current time stamp.
- You take the password the user enters, append the time stamp, then encrypt it.
- Pass back the encrypted password to the server with the time stamp.
- Have the server make sure that the returned data is recent, let it check the encrypted password against its own math.
- If the time stamp is too old *or has been used to log in already* reject it.

This is still a lousy idea, but it isn't as lousy as sending plain text passwords.

Use SSL.  Really.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that OP *really* should use SSL. :)

Comment: @PeeHaa -- Oh.. sorry.  I'll have to fix that.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 4):

Using a secure SSL connection is the only real way to ensure the form data is encrypted. However you could use a bit of JavaScript to encode the password in some way before sending. It won't provide much security (since anyone who can view your site can see the JavaScript and reverse-engineer it) but it does at least avoid sending plain-text passwords around.

Comment: More importantly, if a user of your site is being MITMed, the attacker can easily disable whatever script is performing the encryption, or modify it to send them a copy of the clear text. **Javascript encryption over HTTP is fundamentally unreliable.**

Comment: @duskwuff, He mentioned it here `It won't provide much security (since anyone who can view your site can see the JavaScript and reverse-engineer it) but it does at least avoid sending plain-text passwords around`.